# Any implementation of Reverse Soundex in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, soundex

I have gone through soundex phonetic algorithm. There is another algorithm on Wikipedia called "Reverse Soundex" which is an improved version of soundex. I couldn't find anything about its implementation. Can you point me to the implementation of this algorithm or any pre-built function in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have implementation details since "Reverse Soundex" is very similar to the original algorithm. as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex#Variants) states: `"Reverse Soundex" prefixes the last letter of the name instead of the first`. So the algorithm will be exactly like the [original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex#American_Soundex) (again from Wiki) but stage 1 will be something like:

```
1. Retain the last letter of the name and drop all other occurrences of a, e, i, o, u, y, h, w.
```

So for example `Robert` will now be `t616` (instead of `R163`), no 3 since we remove the `T` at the end.

You can also find some more documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=statements-soundex-phonetic-coding), including some information on when to use this algorithm variation. And if you manage to create a setup you can test your algorithm implementation with this.

Note: You can find a Python implementation of the original `Soundex` algorithm in the [Fuzzy](https://github.com/yougov/Fuzzy) lib.